# What's the best way to emulate a firebug workflow for css in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer, firebug

So I do quite a lot of CSS development, and I work with Firefox / Firebug A LOT. I generally know how to debug for IE6/IE7 (as far as techniques) and if I have the source, I can easily just edit the actual files and run a local server on a linux machine and test it in IE, going back and forth until it's fixed.

I find myself lately being asked to debug problems in IE6 when I don't have the source. Is there anyway to emulate a firebug like flow in IE6?

Firebug Lite doesn't allow you to change css values, nor does IETester. It doesn't necessarily have to be an inline tool (maybe there is some utility to quickly download 1 off webpages and their dependencies), but I'm definitely looking for the most productive solution to fixing bugs in IE when I don't have the source readily available to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [IE Dev Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

It's not as convenient or user-friendly as Firebug, but it can modify CSS and HTML attributes.

Comment: I've used that tool before... I either didn't know or forgot that it could modify CSS on the fly...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) is the best way to debug html in IE.

> Firebug is an extension for Firefox,
>   but what happens when you need to test
>   your pages in Internet Explorer,
>   Opera, and Safari?
>
> The solution is Firebug Lite, a
>   JavaScript file you can insert into
>   your pages to simulate some Firebug
>   features in browsers that are not
>   named "Firefox".
>
> Firebug Lite creates the variable
>   "firebug" and doesn't affect or
>   interfere with HTML elements that
>   aren't created by itself.

Since you already know about it and it doesn't fit what you need, take a look at [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/). There is also a [MS solution with Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

Comment: Yes, he does.  Read the question.

Comment: fastest gun problem :\ Ok I'll fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Why, [the IE developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) of course!

It allows manipulation of HTML and CSS values.

Comment: It does not come with a JS debugger, although IE8's developer tools do.

Answer (score 0):

you have tryed [Internet Explorer developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

3 solutions which i use always

1. Use IE 8 with developer toolbar in IE 7 emulation mode to solve problems of IE 7 and for IE 8 use in normal mode
2. for IE 6 it's best till date for me i use this a lot http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/?p=7
3. and this to judge right selectors it's very good http://www.westciv.com/mri/ ( i use this for all browser, because it can tell perfect selector for element )

**Firebug lite and IE developer toolbar on IE7 not much useful**